# Strange behavior of <p> inside of <div>

Tags: html

When I put a p inside of a div, An extra blank line appears after the /div.  Even weirder, if I use padding in the div, the extra blank line appears before the closing /div.  This shows up in all the major browsers.  One suggestion was that padding the p tag caused this, but there is no styling on the p.  Test code:

```css
body {
  background-color: pink;
}

.whitebox {
  background-color: white;
}

.whitebox2 {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="whitebox">
  Here is some text inside of the whitebox div.
</div>

More text here outside of div.

<div class="whitebox">
  Here is more text in a new whitebox div.
  <p>
    Here is the 2nd paragraph in the div.
</div>

Yet more text outside of div.

<div class="whitebox2">
  Here is text in a whitebox2 div.
  <p>
    Here is the 2nd paragraph in the div.
</div>
And some final text here.
```

Comment: you're not closing the `<p>` tag, which messes up the HTML structure

Comment: Invalid HTML always does weird things.... https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Comment: vote to close coused by typo

Comment: I've tried closing the p tag and nothing changes.

Comment: The `p` tag has a margin by default,  which will also come into play. Look into [margin collapse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing)

Comment: Have run through the validator and got a cryptic message about head tags but no complaint about a p inside a div.  Googling turns up many statements that p is legal inside a div.  So if the HTML is invalid, please indicate why?

Comment: What was invalid was not closing the `p` tag. It is most certainly valid inside a `div`, but the `p` tag must also be closed inside that `div`

Comment: Thank you Jon P!  Yes, this seems to be it.  The article is esoteric and doesn't really give me a clue on how to fix, but at least I have something to google.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="whitebox">
  Here is more text in a new whitebox div.
  <p>
    Here is the 2nd paragraph in the div.
</div>
```

It seems you haven't closed your p tag's `</p>`  at two instances . `<p> ... </p>` is a paired element and will only work when used as its syntax is.

Comment: No, the behavior continues when I close the p.

Answer (score 0):

I found a hack to fix this and other collapsed margin issues.  For my current problem, I just added
p { margin-bottom: 0; } to my .css and the problem went away.

Again, closing the p didn't work.

Comment: Just remove `padding: 10px` from .whitebox2. It will be fixed